# Stack Overflow logo moves up / down one pixel when tabbing only to jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

If you are on Stack Overflow and click questions / documentation / tags (everything but the jobs tab) the logo is in the same spot.  If you click the jobs tab the logo slightly moves up / down when going from one tab to the other.

Reproduce:

1. Click questions
2. Click documentation
3. Click tags
4. Notice all three from above did not shift the so logo
5. Now click jobs - the logo slightly moves (by exactly one pixel)

Comment: Where is the circle-hat?

Comment: @MarounMaroun - It's no longer jolly time.  Back to work buddy!

Comment: Just came to report the same thing. This is driving me mad…

Comment: This seems to have been fixed sometime in the past couple of years, so I'm marking it as [[meta-tag:status-completed]].

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by a `line-height: 1.375;` on `body` that seems to override the normal `line-height:1.3em`. Disabling that rule moves the logo up by 1 pixel (amongst some other small visual changes).

Comment: I should get a stackoverflow JACKET for this!